# How to share data between angular's services and components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, data-binding

How to bind data between services and components in real time way.

let's suppose `isAuthenticated` a public variable for Authentication service that is affecting some view in a component. My question is how to subscribe to `isAuthenticated` variable?

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Authentication {

  isAuthenticated:boolean = false;

  login() {
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', 'true');
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
  }
}
```

Component:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
private isAuthenticated:boolean = false;
  constructor(public authService: Authentication) { 
   this.isAuthenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated'
  }
}
```

home.html

```
...
<div *ngIf="isAuthenticated">Authentication view</div>
<div *ngIf="!isAuthenticated">Unauthentication view</div>
...
```

By the current flow above, the binding is working well but isn't real time.

So what is the best approach:

1- Create an observable inside the Authentication service in order to subscribe to it inside the component.

2- Binding using the following way:

```
...
<div *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated">Authentication view</div>
<div *ngIf="!authService.isAuthenticated">Unauthentication view</div>
...
```

> The second approach is working well but I don't know if it is the best practice.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't execute requests from in a constructor (ie. calling your service to check isAuthenticated). Implement `OnInit` instead on your component and do it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `BehaviorSubject`. It's an `Observable`, so you can subscribe to it, but you can also control when it emits new values by calling `behaviorSubject.next(newValue)`. When creating BehaviorSubject you must pass inital value to it. In your case it's `false`.

```
@Injectable()
export class Authentication {

  isAuthenticated = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  login() {
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', 'true');
    this.isAuthenticated.next(true);
  }

}
```

-

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  private isAuthenticated:boolean;

  constructor(public authService: Authentication) { 
   this.authService.isAuthenticated
    .subscribe(isAuthenticated => this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated)
  }

}
```

or you can subscribe in html with Async Pipe

```
export class HomePage {

  private isAuthenticated: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

  constructor(public authService: Authentication) { 
   this.isAuthenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated;
  }

}
```

-

```
<div *ngIf="isAuthenticated | async">Authentication view</div>
<div *ngIf="!(isAuthenticated | async)">Unauthentication view</div>
```

Unlike regular Observable, when you call subscribe on BehaviorSubject, the function you passed as an argument to subscribe will be immediately executed. This is because BehaviorSubject always has a value. You can access it with `this.authService.isAuthenticated.value` but it's not very useful here.

Comment: How to import BehaviorSubject?

Comment: which version of RxJS are you using?

Comment: for RxJS v6+ you can import it like this `import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your tag you are using Ionic framework? Could this maybe be done using events?

```
    // first page (publish an event when a user is created)
constructor(public events: Events) {}
createUser(user) {
  console.log('User created!')
  this.events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
}


// second page (listen for the user created event after function is called)
constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
    // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
    console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
  });
}
```

Example code taken from: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/util/Events/

Comment: it's possible to create the event in a provider(service)?

Comment: It should be possible but I am not sure if it is best practice, what is calling the "login" method? This could be changed so that it returns an observable or a promise and then from this call the Ionic event (assuming what is calling it is not on the same page that you are calling "login" from in which case the event would not be necessary).

Comment: I don't think u can change the event value like ...next(false) or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Make use of RXJS. Using BehaviourSubjects allows you to push state and subscribe to state changes throughout multiple components that inject the service and have an initial state. When defining a BehaviourSubject you must also define a starting value which here is false. All you have to do is call `.next(true)` on the BehaviourSubject to push state as shown below:

```
...
@Injectable()
export class Authentication {

  private _isAuthenticated: BehaviourSubject<boolean> = new BehaviourSubject(false);

  public get isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._isAuthenticated.asObservable();
  }

  login() {
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', 'true');
    this._isAuthenticated.next(true);
  }
}
```

Using a get method on your service allows you to return an observable without publically exposing the methods on the BehaviourSubject.

Then in your component:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  private isAuthenticated:boolean = false;
  private readonly _authService: Authentication;
  constructor(authService: Authentication) {
    this._authService = authService;
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
   this._authService.isAuthenticated
     .subscribe((isAuthenticated) => this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I'm using this solution:

```
import { DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

//...

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  private isAuthenticated:boolean = false;
  constructor(public authService: Authentication) { }

  ngDoCheck() {
      if (this.authService.isAuthenticated)) {
        //..if authenticated do this
      } else {
        //..if not do this
      }
  }
}
```

Even if I'm not sure this is a nice way.